How to prevent Preview-Pane to enlarge, every time Windows-Explorer is subsequently launched?
From EXCEL VBA, these 3 lines of code calls Windows-Explorer to display a *.TIF image in a folder that contains hundreds of small TIFF images of same size.
FullPathNameTIF = “C:\SomeFolder\someTIFFfile.tif”
shellCMD = "explorer.exe /select, " & FullPathNameTIF
Shell (shellCMD), vbMaximizedFocus

In Window-Explorer the Preview-Pane is present. Which means the opened TIFF file is selected and displayed in the Preview-Pane.
After the image is displayed, the user can close Window-Explorer.
Windows-Explorer behave strangely. Every time a subsequent TIFF image is called from VBA, the Window-Explorer Preview-Pane will enlarge and the number of columns displaying all TIFF files to the left, will shrink from n columns to n-1 columns. After 5 or 6 calls, files in Window-Explorer will be displayed on One Only column and the Preview-Pane will be at its maximum possible size. Why is the Preview-Pane getting larger and larger at each subsequent Explorer launch ?
Questions: How to prevent Preview-Pane to enlarge every time Windows-Explorer is subsequently launched ? Is there a way to call Window-Explorer with a fixed Preview-Pane size ?
Thanks for the help
